# Как запретить изменять размеры окна qt?

Tags: qt

Как запретить изменять размеры окна в qt?

Answer (score 2):

`QWidget::setFixedSize(const QSize &s)` из [QT источника](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize)

Answer (score 2):

Ещё проще можно в Design-ере задать окну максимальные и минимальные ширину и высоту одинаковыми (соответственно) и, чтобы эта область не казалась пользователю сырой, убираем курсоры изменения размеров окна, которые появляются при наведении на его границы:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
```